# Use cookie authentication in mvc5 project with web api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We have an application in production built in mvc5 with cookie authentication. We added a component to this project that uses web api controller. When a logged in user tries to access the part of the system that uses web api the controller is asking them to sign in again. Is there a way to make web api use the same cookie authentication as the mvc controllers?

Comment: Is the WebApi controller on the same domain?  What are you using to validate the cookie on the WebApi controller?

Comment: The web api controller is within the same project as my mvc5 controllers.

Comment: And how are you validating the cookie on the WebAPI controller?

Comment: [Authorize] is all I am doing.. we built the whole app without authorize for fiddler and now that its done we noticed this issue.. lol

Comment: can we take token from cookie and pass it as access bearer? I assume this wouldn't work

Comment: meh no simple solution i'll just use rest inside an mvc5 controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot authenticate WebApi by the use of cookies. If you want to a secured WebApi you should implement your access token generation.

Comment: yeah that turned out to be the answer. I just converted everything into an mvc controller which works almost the same.